# EF Core with SQL Server persistence requires VIEW SERVER STATE permissions?

Tags: entity-framework-core

If I use EF Core against SQL Server, and the user account on the connection does not have permissions for VIEW SERVER STATE on object 'server', database 'master', the operation will fail with a DBUpdateException stating that this permission is missing.

What is EF Core trying to do that requires this permission? Is there any way for me to disable whatever it is doing that requires it? or do I have to add this permission?

Comment: Stack Trace: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'. The user does not have permission to perform this action. at

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any access to the tables like sys.dm_tran_active_transactions, sys.dm_tran_current_transaction when you do the save changes in EF. Maybe it could be through a table trigger. I faced a similar issue due to a trigger trying to access those sys tables.