# Why does EF need VIEW SERVER STATE permission

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We created new account (with all permissions granted - as we thought) in our database for web application (.NET MVC with Entity Framework 6.1.3) and an error appeared:

```
SqlException: VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'. The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

So we found out we must grant VIEW SERVER STATE to that user and that's ok, but we cannot find out why EF needs that permission? Have you any idea?

Comment: With which query are you getting the error ?

Comment: Related to the unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347476/ef-core-with-sql-server-persistence-requires-view-server-state-permissions

Comment: @Stormcloak It appear with SaveChanges()

Comment: Which SQL Server version you're using? I read that you need to execute `GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [username]` command, here is related issue in DBA: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118452/error-message-view-server-state-permission-was-denied-when-connecting-to-sql.

Comment: If you enable EF logging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083470/how-to-make-ef-log-sql-queries-globally you can see all the statements it executes.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it is SQL Server 2014 version 12.0.4213.0

Comment: @rene Good point, i will try that.

Comment: @ShiwanginiShishulkar I don't know why you commenting with this link. I have a problem when application connecting to database through Entity Framework and my question was why app need this permission. You just paste some random url that you find, which has nothing to do with my question. If you have nothing helpful or you don't need some clarification, please don't comment. It will be better for you and for everybody because it takes some time for me to find out it is not helpful and write this comment and, I believe, it takes some time to you too.